# How to fill entire calendar header from border to border?

Tags: html, css, background, header, fill

I can't fill all header, for example, with red color, because it's filling only in the area of text and I need to be filled from top left corner grey area to where days are starting.
Here is html:

```
  <div id="calendar-container">
     <div id="calendar-header">
       <span id="calendar-month-year"></span>
       <div id="calendar-dates"></div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

and css:

```
  #calendar-container{
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 280px;
  height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 19px;
  color: #e4e4e5;
  font-family: Calibri;
  background: #323439;
}
#calendar-header{
  background-color: red;
  height: 30px;
}
#calendar-container>div{
  padding: 0;

  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#calendar-dates>table>tr>td{
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

and my result now:

[image: my result]

Comment: Is it because your `#calendar-container` has `padding: 15px;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

## 1.

Remove the padding from `#calendar-container`, and add it to `#calendar-dates`.

```css
  #calendar-container {
    margin-left: 50px;
    /*margin-top: -50px;*/
    /*padding: 15px;  */
    width: 280px;
    height: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 19px;
    color: #e4e4e5;
    font-family: Calibri;
    background: #323439;
  }
  #calendar-header {
    background-color: red;
    height: 30px;
  }
  #calendar-container>div {
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  #calendar-dates {
    padding: 15px;
  }
  #calendar-dates>table>tr>td {
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="calendar-container">
  <div id="calendar-header">
    <span id="calendar-month-year">May 2015</span>
    <div id="calendar-dates">dates dates dates dates dates dates dates</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## 2.

Add a negative margin to `#calendar-month-year` of `-15px`, so it overlaps the padding from its parent.

```css
#calendar-container {
  margin-left: 50px;
  /*margin-top: -50px;*/
  padding: 15px;
  width: 280px;
  height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 19px;
  color: #e4e4e5;
  font-family: Calibri;
  background: #323439;
}
#calendar-header {
  background-color: red;
  height: 30px;
  margin: -15px;
}
#calendar-container>div {
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#calendar-dates>table>tr>td {
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="calendar-container">
  <div id="calendar-header">
    <span id="calendar-month-year">May 2015</span>
    <div id="calendar-dates">dates dates dates dates dates dates dates</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're attempting to get the red area to 100% width. To do so, limit the left and right padding on #calendar-container to **padding: 15px 0**

Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Your `#calendar-container` has a padding of `15px`. Remove that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `absolute` positing for your `#calendar-header`.

Update `#calendar-container` to this:

```
 #calendar-container{
  ...
  padding:45px 15px 15px 15px; /*30px top for header height + 15px extra padding*/
   position: relative;
}
```

And then add these styles to `#calendar-header`:

```
#calendar-header{
  ...
  height:30px;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
}
```